# Returning words that begins with a specific letter

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to returns words from an arraylist that started with a specific letter, I chose the letter c, however; I was told that I could do this another way, and other than specifically returning each element that started with the letter with many println's I would not know how else to do this other than using the ArrayList startswith method, anyone care to enlighten me?

```
public static ArrayList<String> letterC(ArrayList<String> list)
{
    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> letterC = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sweet = "c"; 
    animals.add("cape");
    animals.add("dog");
    animals.add("cougar");
    animals.add("moon");
    animals.add("conor");
    animals.add("bob");
    animals.add("tiger");
    animals.add("sun");
    for(int i = 0; i<animals.size(); i++) {
        if(animals.get(i).startsWith(sweet.toUpperCase())) {
            letterC.add(animals.get(i));
        }
        if(animals.get(i).startsWith(sweet)) {
            letterC.add(animals.get(i));
        }
    }
    if(letterC.size() >= 1) {
        letterC.remove(1);
        letterC.remove(letterC.size() - 1);
    }
    return letterC;
}
```

}

Comment: `animals.get(index).charAt(0);`

Comment: That's only if theres an uppercase C animal though right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing at the end when you check if `letterC.size() > = 1`.  Why do you want to remove elements from the list?  It seems like you should just return the list at this point, since it will contain all animal names that begin with `C`.

Comment: `animals.get(index).startsWith(sweet);` or if you don't care about the case `animals.get(index).toLowerCase().startsWith(sweet.toLowerCase());`

Comment: @qvd - Yep... Sorry, I misread that.  It's fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<animals.size(); i++) {
    if(animals.get(i).substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(sweet)) {
        letterC.add(animals.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: You should edit the first if-statement, since primitive data types don't have methods. (`char.equalsIgnoreCase`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick error check of that. Whew. Only realized it after I wrote it.

Comment: Ahh yes! Substrings! didn't think about that.